# Problem in analyzing asymptotic notation in using The Master Theorem

Tags: master-theorem

As we know for master theorem:
T(n)=aT(n/b)+Θ(nd) this formate is required..
But for 
T(n)=2T(n/2)+2^n
If I want to apply theorem what will be value of d here?
We cant just take d=2 here..right?

Comment: This is covered by Case 3 of the master theorem as stated on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The master theorem concerns recurrence relations of the form:

$T(n)=aT(n/b)+\color{red}{f(n)}$ this formate is required, where $a\geqslant 1, b>1$

This fits for case 3 of the theorem:

$f(n)=\Theta(n^c)$ where $c>\log _2 2=1$ can you procced from here?